# React Drag and Drop plugin suggestion

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on with a working model like this:

[image]

[image]

So here, the left side is a simple list which containse list items.
   1. This is not droppable, draggable only
   2. After drag, this list remains same all the time.

On the right side, the dragged item will be dropped here.

1. Once the user dragged an item from left side, the other side/ right side should indicate a placeholders to user where they can drop.
2. All the dropped items on the right side can be swappable within right side.
3. Right side area should contain like bootstrap row, column functionality.

I have to achieve something similar to this https://react-email-editor-demo.netlify.com/

Already, I gone through fre react plugins like react dnd and react -beautiful-dnd. I don't get an idea like whether above points are achievable by using these two plugins.

After searched many things,In react-beautiful-dnd, we can't add custom placeholders.

Any help  on this, would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dzipd7) I created for you a small example that tries to replicate the drag in a placeholder behavior from the link you shared above.

Keep in mind that you have total freedom to create how many droppable targets as you want and make them accept different types of items, based on what you specify in `accept` array of `useDrop` hook.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Finally I got a solution to choose React Dnd. One more query since I'm new to react dnd. Can we make each list iteam as draggable/swappable within Container side after dropped

Comment: Yes, you can put useDrag hook on the list item component to make them draggable. Check this example http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/examples/sortable/simple to make them swappable.

Answer (score 0):

[React DND](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd) is the most popular library. However, it is not impossible to implement your own. Please, have a look on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402808/how-to-drag-and-drop-content-with-react/57264927#57264927).

Comment: by using react dnd, am i able to customize the things i want, like custom placeholder which like a droppable area

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about the placeholder suggestion bit but Dragula JS is a quite easy library to use for drag and drop features. You can check it on github and see the demos there too.

https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula

Demo page - https://bevacqua.github.io/dragula

Hope this helps.