# to create a sample project where we can drag and drop elements from tool bar to a div/ editor in react js

Tags: html, css, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I'm a beginner in React and even in HTML. I  need to create a drag and drop application with functionality like https://app.letter.so/try. I need to drag element ( text/button) from toolbox and need to place anywhere in a div. I did it partially by using react-rnd. I did it by wrapping controls in toolbar section in . And it works. But it removes controls from that toolbar while we drag. And also I kept element as button/text(controls) in toolbar. Instead of that I want  controls to be placed in div only on dropping control in div. I have attached a pic to show the desired result[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/segqC.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Drag and Drop plugin suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58183717/react-drag-and-drop-plugin-suggestion)

Comment: no. While dropping i need to display a text/button respectively. And also i need to drop anywhere i want . not a specific container